# How to sort and limit result from multiple indices in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I've 4 indices called index1, idndex2, index3 and index4

Lets say there are hundreds result in resultset
Now I want only

```
top 10 rows/result from index1
+
top 10 rows/result from index2
+
top 10 rows/result from index3
+
top 10 rows/result from index4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Multi-Search API of Elasticsearch.
Don't provide any index name in the url , instead use the _msearch keyword in the url as below :

```
GET _msearch
{"index" : "index1"}
{"query" : {}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{"index" : "index2"}
{"query" : {}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
```

reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Alternatively, you can also perform a single query across multiple indices and then group the results using aggregations by index name;specify the top_hits size as 10 to get the top 10 hits from each index.

```
GET index1,index2,index3/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { ... },
  "aggs": {
    "indexes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Before I was using below json body to get selected fields from index, now I'm all confused where to use below  "_source" in your example

`{
    "_source": [
     "id",
     "sclPostArticlesECO.title",
     "sclPostQuestionECO.sclSubjectiveQuesECO.title",
     "sclPostQuestionECO.sclPostMcqECO.title",
     "sclPostPollECO.title",
     "firstName",
     "middleName",
     "lastName"
    ]
}`

Comment: The "_source" goes at the same level as "query" , "aggs" and "size" but try to keep everything on the same line , please try and let know if something like this works with _msearch :  {"index" : "index1"}
                                     {"_source":{} , "query" : {}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}                           notice that the source, query , from and size are not indented but in a continuous line , as multisearch api checks the new line character to understand index and request body when parsing the json body.

Comment: I'm using **Alternatively way** and placed **"_source" ** at same level and getting entire doc instead selected attributes(fields)