# How to get limited results from Multiple Queries (x records from query 1 and y records from query 2) in Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have two distinct queries, and I want to get a combined result from them, i.e. x number of records from query 1 and y number of records from query 2. 
How do I do that?

Currently I am using the query below:

```
 **{ "bool" : {
  "should" : [
   {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "indea",
      "fields" : [
        "admin^1.0",
        "city^1.0",
        "country^1.0"
      ],
      "type" : "best_fields",
      "operator" : "OR",
      "slop" : 0,
      "fuzziness" : "2",
      "prefix_length" : 0,
      "max_expansions" : 50,
      "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
     }
    },
   {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "Maharashtra",
      "fields" : [
        "admin^1.0"
      ],
      "type" : "best_fields",
      "operator" : "OR",
      "slop" : 0,
      "prefix_length" : 0,
      "max_expansions" : 50,
      "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
      }
   }
 ],
 "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
 "boost" : 1.0
  }
}**
```

Comment: take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57568601/11259999

Comment: hay @soumitragoswami thanks for your suggestions , but i have same index and i want to get result on the basis of different queries.

Comment: You can use different queries for the same index in multisearch so in the example for you , index1 and index2 are same, the result will have a array of hits for both the queries on the same index. be careful with the formatting though , as msearch  makes use of the newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) format.